# How to help AWS EC2 crontab find a package?

Tags: linux, python, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and Linux. I just set up my first AWS EC2 instance, (Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM)), transferred a simple Python project to it with scp, connected to the instance with ssh, installed Python3, pip, pipenv and project dependencies, and ran the project. Everything works as expected. I then added a crontab to the project:

```
*/5 * * * * cd my_project && pipenv run python3 test.py
```

After a few moments, I get a message in the command line.

```
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/ec2-user
```

The message is this:

```
/bin/sh: pipenv: command not found
```

From another post: `...cron doesn't have the same environment ie $PATH as the user entering the cron script data`. I'm not really clear on what this means or how to go about remedying the situation. I tried looking in the /bin/sh file to see if I could just add pipenv to it, but it's just chaos in there, not human readable.

I used `which pipenv` to find out where pipenv was installed, and the path I got was `~/.local/bin/pipenv`. If I try to cd into that directory, I get: `-bash: cd: /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/pipenv: Not a directory`. If I `cd /bin` and `ls`, I see that Python3 and pip are installed here, but not pipenv. It probably bears mentioning that I installed Python3 and pip with yum, but installed pipenv with pip.

Any insight on what's going on here for a more or less complete Linux newbie would be very much appreciated.

Edit: Shortly after posting, I found this...

```
cron runs your command in a restricted environment.

What environment variables are available is likely to be very limited. Typically, you'll only get a few variables defined, such as $LOGNAME, $HOME, and $PATH.

Of particular note is the PATH is restricted to /bin:/usr/bin. The vast majority of "my cron script doesn't work" problems are caused by this restrictive path. If your command is in a different location you can solve this in a couple of ways:

    Provide the full path to your command.

    1 2 * * * /path/to/your/command

    Provide a suitable PATH in the crontab file

    PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/path/to/something/else
    1 2 * * * command
```

It looks like I either need to get pipenv installed in `/usr/bin` or tell cron where to find pipenv. I definitely don't know how to do the former, and although I know the path to pipenv, as mentioned previously, I got a message that it doesn't exist when I tried to go there, so I'm not sure how to do the latter either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the `directory not found` error because you tried to `cd` into the file, not the directory. Instead of this: `cd /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/pipenv`, use this `cd /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/` and then `ls -l` or this `ls -l /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/pipenv` and you'll see it.

In your crontab, use either of the following:

```
*/5 * * * * cd my_project && /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/pipenv run /usr/bin/python3 test.py
```

### -------------------------------

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin

*/5 * * * * cd my_project && pipenv run python3 test.py
```

Make sure that there is a new line after the last line.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much for your help. Part of what I was missing is that I needed `/home/ec2-user/.local/bin` rather than `~/.local/bin`.